# How to make GLPlane always have front-to-camera direction ( Delphi, GLScene )

Tags: delphi, glscene

I have a GLScene with a camera that rotates by mouse events

```
procedure TForm1.GLSceneViewer1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  mdx:=X;
  mdy:=Y;
end;
    
procedure TForm1.GLSceneViewer1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
 if Shift=[ssRight] then 
   GLCamera1.MoveAllAroundTarget(mdy - Y, mdx - X);
end;
```

I need GPPlane1 to always be front-facing towards the camera